# Is it good idea to send email to HR highlighting achievements?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

I am looking forward to switch to some better organizations. 2 weeks ago I gave a very thorough technical interview at a company and I did well in it. I was called for final meeting with GM a few days later and that interview also went very well.

So yesterday I contacted the HR to ask about my interview status and they said that I am selected but the position is currently on hold.
I had some contacts inside that company who told me that the team lead of the project was looking for a resource having 4+ years of experience but I am so far at the top of line and I have almost 3 years of experience.

I was wondering that will it be wise to send an email to HR telling them about my accomplishments at current position i.e. I am leading a team in which there are 2 sub ordinates have more then 4 years of experience and such other things?
If so then how should I approach them?

Comment: This should have gone in your cover letter or your CV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't see any benefits to sending such an email to the HR after the interview. All your important achievements should have been already presented in your resume, and discussed in detail during the interview. The interview is your opportunity to sell yourself. If you did not fully utilize it, too bad, learn from the experience and do better next time.

They have already made their decision based on their interactions with you so far (reading your resume, multiple rounds of interview, etc.), it is borderline silly to go back to them with what is essentially a request to "extend" the interview (albeit over email), where you can impress them with more of your achievements.

Doing so also reveals that you are not confident of your own strengths, which in turn means you are likely to be "weak" during salary negotiations (if they make you an offer later).

When the HR told you the position is put on hold, but you are still within the "zone of consideration", it means they will wait for a certain duration to see if a better candidate comes along. If no such person turns up, they might advance your candidature to the next step (such as making you an offer).

The standard advice when you have been "put on hold", of course, is to keep looking for other opportunities. That is a lot more fruitful use of your time than knocking the same door repeatedly till it opens.

Comment: `Doing so also reveals that you are not confident of your own strengths, which in turn means you are likely to be "weak" during salary negotiations`. How does this make someone weak?

Comment: @mayu The first salary offered by HR becomes the anchor point for the negotiation. By revealing to HR that you are somewhat desperate to get the job and also somewhat lacking in confidence, you are giving them an "opportunity" to lower the initial offer. While you could theoretically still negotiate "hard" after a "timid" first impression, that is highly difficult to pull off in practice. When it comes to job search and especially during salary negotiation, you should appear as confident as you can, even if you are not.

Answer (score -1):

@Masked-Man's answer is very black and white which I think is inappropriate for the nuanced world of getting a job.

It is commonly assumed that one should not push too hard during the recruitment process. However this is not a law of physics, it's a convention. Also, what is *too hard*?

If the job you applied for is great, keep knocking.

@rollo, write the email.